# Database error because of Configurations.PHP file cannot access website

Tags: php, mysql, joomla, phpmyadmin

I have a Joomla website that I am hosting with GoDaddy. I changed the phpMyAdmin password and now I receive the following error when I try to load my website:

```
Database Error: Unable to connect to the database:Could not connect to MySQL
```

I'm freaking out right now because I don't want to get my boss mad.

After some frantic googling I came across this:

http://docs.joomla.org/Unable_to_connect_to_the_database

Apparently I have to change my configuration.php file in phpMyAdmin; however, I have no idea how to access it despite all my research.

[image]

Comment: If you call GoDaddy, they have backed up everything.  Ask them for a system restore.

Comment: `configuration.php` isn't in your MySQL server. It's a configuration file on your server. Change the password back or modify this file with the new password.

Comment: I think it would be helpful if you guys atleast answered how for him. He seems to lack in experience with Joomla and servers

Comment: Fess up to someone who knows what he's doing, get it fixed ASAP, get yelled at, learn from it, move on with life.

Comment: ^ before you incur even more downtime than you already have!

Comment: Thanks guys. Would it be done through GoDaddy? just asking because I don't have anyone else  to ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the root of your Joomla website there's a file titled **configuration.php**

If you know how to SFTP to your site, open this file with a text editor. Alternatively use your GoDaddy control panel, find the file manager and open this same configuration.php file.

Look for the line:
public $password = 'your_old_password';

Change the password (between the single quotes) and save your updates.

All should be good after that.

Good luck!

or **PLAN B**
Change your phpMyAdmin password back to what it was initially and then there's no need to touch the configuration.php file ;)

Answer (score 0):

Its a literal file in your web server file structure, Joomla probably mentions it in the setup. You need to download it via FTP, change the password, then upload the new version. Then the system should work again.